# How should I publish artifacts to an artifact repository to assure that I can easily get the right binary?

Tags: git, nexus, artifactory, changeset, archiva

We are DSCM and building different branches, forks or pull requests and now I am trying to migrate to a model where we publish the binaries in an Artifact Repository (like [Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix))

This has nothing to do with Java as my binaries but it seems that the only well grown generic enough solutions are those listed above.

The biggest requirement is that I want to be able to get the artefact based on the changeset from the repository.

The problem is that I discovered that artefacts are identified only by their product and version and that the version formatting has some very strict rules.

How can I do this? Does anyone solved this problem already?

Answer (score 0):

Artifact repositories like Nexus and Artifactory are designed to store the files that are created from your source code. Generally one only does this when releasing software so it would be expected to have some sort of incrementing release number.

All source code repositories have a mechanism to "tag" the code at a particular point in time. This should be done every time you create a release, and subsequently push the resultant file(s) to Nexus/Artifactory.

There are lots and lots of strategies for creating a release number. There are some nifty approaches that use the number of commits in Git to generate a unique number:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141973/how-do-you-achieve-a-numeric-versioning-scheme-with-git
- http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/using-git-to-version-stamp-chef-artifacts